# How to get data from intermediate table in eloquent, silex

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, silex

I created database tables `users`, `groups`, and `group_user` (MySQL).And `group_user` table (intermediate table) contains the `user_id` and `role_id`. users and groups relationship is many to many. I want to delete a group in `groups` table. Before deleting a group, I want to check if there is any user belongs to that group. 
I tried to do it this way.

Group.php (Model)

```
 public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\Modules\User\Models\User');
    }
```

Service.php

```
public function deleteGroup($data) {
    if (!isset($data['groupID']))
        return ['error' => 'Failed to delete group. Group id is required'];

    $group = Group::find($data['groupID']);
    if (!$group)
        return ['error' => 'Failed to delete group. Group not found'];

    // check any user belongs to group. 
    $result = $group->users()->pivot->user_id;

    if(!$result){
       $group->delete();
       return ['success' => 'Successfully delete group.'];
    }
    return ['error' => 'Failed to delete group. Group not found'];
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: You should copy&paste the text of the error an not an (incomplete) image :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it out.

service.php

```
public function deleteGroup($data) {

    $group = Group::find($data['groupID']);
    if (!$group){
        return [
            "msg" => "Failed to delete group. Group not found."
        ];
    }
    // find out any one belongs to the group.           
    $result = $group->users->first()->userID;
    if ($result){
        return [
            "msg" => "Failed to delete group. Group has users."
        ];
    }

    $result = $group->delete($data['groupID']);
    if(!$result){
        return [
            "msg" => "Failed to delete group."
        ];
    }

    return [
        "msg" => "Successfully deleted group."
    ];
}
```

This is how I do it. If there is another way please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Also you can do like this.                                                                                         $result = $group->users->count();
            
            if ($result>0) {
                return $this->response(true, $errMsg . 'Group has users');
            }else {
                $group->delete($data['groupID']);
                return $this->response(false, 'Group deleted successfully');
            }'